# SVN branches and virtual hosts

Tags: apache, svn, branch, virtual, hosts

I come from a GIT background and now have to work using SVN.
Usually, when working with GIT, I had Apache virtual host set up to one folder as document root and when I wanted to switch branches I just did git checkout branch.

From what I see with SVN now, when I make branches I have to make a new folder for each branch. Is that true or is there some other way to accomplish to what I'm used to with GIT?

Because, that would mean I have to make a number of different virtual hosts or use wildcard dns or something.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) to switch your working copy to a different branch, if you want to keep it in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Subversion branching is just copying a tree so yes, you would be creating a new folder. Have a look at the SVN book for their chapter on branching/merging: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html

There's no natural mapping between virtual hosts and version control systems like Subversion or git so I'm afraid I can't comment on how it might relate to your different vHosts. Maybe you could talk about your setup a little more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having something like:

```
    <VirtualHost [server's IP address]:443>
     ServerName svn.example.com
     <Location />
       DAV svn
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "svn.example.com"
       AuthUserFile /var/local/svn/svn.example.com/conf/passwd
       AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/local/svn/svn.example.com/conf/authz
       SVNPath /var/local/svn/svn.example.com
       Require valid-user
     </Location>

    </VirtualHost>
```

you don't have to worry about handling different branches explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A way to accomplish what you are used to with git is to use [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).